# Using '<' character in Xml Documentation of C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How can I put characters like '<' in C# Xml Documentations:

```
/// <summary>
/// This produces an empty tag like <tagname/>
/// </summary>
public string GenerateEmptyTag(string tagname)
{
    return string.Format("<{0}/>", tagname);
}
```

In above example, the `<tagname/>` in the documentation causes error as it contains `<` character

Answer (score 2):

You should escape it, like you would do with XML since the inline documentation is Visual Studio is in fact a XML fragment:

```
/// This produces an empty tag like &lt;tagname/&gt;
```

Comment: why is this not accepted as the answer?

Comment: @katia: Don't ask me :)